# Not getting any result when evaluating example of WikipediaData taken from documentation

Tags: internet, wikipedia

[image]

I got no output from `WikipediaData` expression..

Comment: Are you sure this isn't due to the "Great Firewall"?

Comment: emmmmmmm,I connected SSR

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can not be reproduced and may be to the particular web environment of the OP.